# Propel subqueries in select

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I need  to find article from database, and also the next and previous id of the neighbours.
Right now i have 3 queries that work - first two are without the find() method - i know that.

```
$artNext = ArticlesQuery::create()
            ->filterById(array('min' => $artId + 1))
            ->filterByActive(1)
            ->filterByType(1)
            ->select('Id')
            ->orderById(Criteria::ASC)
            ->limit(1);


$artPrev = ArticlesQuery::create()
            ->filterById(array('max' => $artId - 1))
            ->filterByActive(1)
            ->filterByType(1)
            ->select('Id')
            ->orderById(Criteria::DESC)
            ->limit(1);


$article = ArticlesQuery::create()
            ->filterByActive(1)
            ->filterById($artId)
            ->findOne();
```

How can i combine artPrev and artNext subqueries to be inserted as in the following query (simplified)

```
select id,
(select id from articles where id<77 ORDER BY id DESC limit 1 ) as prev,
(select id from articles where id>77 ORDER BY id ASC limit 1) as next
from articles 
where id=77
```

Comment: i'm trying to achieve this with propel - but for example - using the "addSelectQuery" method - adds prev and next in the FROM clause. Union also doesn't help me - beacause then i'll get three records instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
$artNext = ArticlesQuery::create()
        ->filterById(array('min' => $artId + 1))
        ->filterByActive(1)
        ->filterByType(1)
        ->select('Id')
        ->orderById(Criteria::ASC)
        ->limit(1);
        ->find();

$artPrev = ArticlesQuery::create()
        ->filterById(array('max' => $artId - 1))
        ->filterByActive(1)
        ->filterByType(1)
        ->select('Id')
        ->orderById(Criteria::DESC)
        ->limit(1);
        ->find();

$article = ArticlesQuery::create()
        ->filterByActive(1)
        ->filterById($artId)
        ->withColumn('Articles.Id','id')
        ->withColumn($artPrev->getId(),'prev')
        ->withColumn($artNext->getId(),'next')      
        ->findOne();
```

Now you can use it like so:

```
$nextString = $article->getNext();
$prevString = $article->getPrev();
$idString = $article->getId();
```

The "->withColumn" acts like a subselect in this case, just with previously determined values:

```
SELECT
    "19" AS prev,
    id
    "21" AS next
FROM
    articles;
```

Comment: Yes, i know, but with this attempt - i'm still getting 3 queries - which are executed while using the find() method. I still search how to do this in one query - using propel.

Comment: @Axel: The database engine will always perform 3 select queries! Your "raw" SQL with the subqueries that you posted above result - imho - in the same: 3 queries and 3 "find()"-Operations. Just because you put them in one request doesn't mean it's less load on the database engine! It might look more elegant, that I agree with. If you want only one database query executed, you need a different approach. I'll post a seperate answer for that right now...

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach:

If your IDs are incremented by 1 and never deleted or omitted, you could do:

```
$article = ArticlesQuery::create()
    ->filterByActive(1)
    ->filterById($artId)
    ->_or()
    ->filterById($artId-1)
    ->_or()
    ->filterById($artId+1)
    ->withColumn('Articles.Id','id')
    ->withColumn(('IF Articles.Id ='.$artId.',"current",(IF Articles.Id ='.$artId+1.',"next","prev"))','position')
    ->find();
```

That gives you an $article Object with three "rows" like this (Assumin your ArtId is 20 again)

```
(0) 
    id=19
    position=prev
(1) 
    id=20
    position=current
(2) 
    id=21
    position=next
```

As I said: Another approach completely. But you have to accept: You cannot merge three queries that aren't "logically related" into one. Even if you make it seem like it by an elegant approach in your programming language or database abstracting layer, it'll always result in three queries executed by the database engine!

Hope this helps!

Comment: For my bad - I know there will be gaps, but thanks :)